# Java return web pages

Tags: java

I want to read more web pages and I have the code to read it

```
public class TestWebPages{
    private static void readPage(String url){
        try {
            URL accessUrl = new URL(url);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(accessUrl.openStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (someCondition)
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but the pages are in cascade, how can I extend this class but to change only the if clause. Is this possible?
I do not want to write the code each time.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. What do mean by "the pages are in cascade"? How are you trying to extend your class?

Comment: I read the a page, this page contains links to others web page and I do not write again this code for each page and change the if condition

Comment: Where would you put all these other cascaded documents? Also just print them?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to implement a web crawler. You can try changing the if condition to check if the line read contains a url using regex or some other method. You would then call your `readPage()` method recursively on the url. If you can only change the `if` block, your very limited on what you can achieve and will run into issues such as your program recursing infinitely on pages with a url pointing to a page you already read. There are ways around this, but implementing them only in the `if` block will be a challenge.